# How to set give multiple values to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm making a program that requires different parts in a variable
 the code goes like this

```
    var num=Math.round(Math.random()*5);
var a;
var a[0]="hi"
/*I've done this before, but remember it as a[num] */
var a[1]...
/*Many vars later*/
console.log(a[num])
```

this code always says that a[] does not work

Comment: Can you show us the extract error ?

Comment: @thangngoc89 I'm usinc Codecademy(a website that runs coding) and it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ["

Comment: var a; 

You need to tell it's an array: var a = [];

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the compiler it's an array

```
var a = [];
a[0] = 'hi';
console.log(a[0]); // => hi
```

Comment: i just realized it did. something doesnt work on my full code

Answer (score 1):

Set this

```
var a;
```

to

```
var a = [];
```

for a declaration of an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

---

Please change this

```
var num=Math.round(Math.random()*5);
```

to

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); // for numbers from 0 to 4
```

because `Math.round` rounds depending up or down. `Math.floor` gets the integer part of a number.

---

```js
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); // for numbers from 0 to 4
var a = [];
a[0] = "ha";
a[1] = "he";
a[2] = "hi";
a[3] = "ho";
a[4] = "hu";
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(a, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write(a[num]);
```